# Android studio Splash Error (It's frozen on the intro screen)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was making an intro screen through Splash.
I have to show the intro screen for 3 seconds and go to the login screen afterwards, but it's still frozen on the intro screen.

What's the problem?
Corresponding source code:

SlashActivity.java (splash class)

public class SlashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

LoginActivity.java

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    EtEmail = findViewById(R.id.EtEmail);
    EtPwd = findViewById(R.id.EtPwd);
    Btn_Register = findViewById(R.id.Btn_Register);
    Btn_Login = findViewById(R.id.Btn_Login);

    Btn_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(EtEmail.getText().length() > 0 && EtPwd.getText().length() > 0) {
                String strEmail = EtEmail.getText().toString();
                String strPwd = EtPwd.getText().toString();
                mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(strEmail, strPwd).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // 로그인 성공
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "로그인 실패", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "아이디와 비밀번호를 확인해주세요.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Btn_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_icon"
    android:label="HomePet"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Project"
    tools:targetApi="31" >

    <activity android:name=".SlashActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".map.MapsActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="MapsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".User_Account"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Useredit_Activity"/>
    <activity android:name=".LogoutActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".NoticeActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".HospitalActivity"
        android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

I would really appreciate your help.

---

why error??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `try` you froze the main thread for 3 seconds. This is not recommended. It will not go into `catch` as it works successfully. You can use this `handler` instead.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did what you wrote, but I see a red error in the loofer and postDelayed, this, LoginActivity.class. Please see the picture attached to the post.

Comment: I think you're missing a braces at the end. You should import the red ones. for windows Alt - Enter , for macOs Option - Enter

Comment: I revised it as you said. However, the same red lines continue to appear in the PostDelayed part and this, LoginActivety.class.

Comment: Check what you imported. Import this `import android.os.Handler;`. Not this import `java.util.logging.Handler;` I edited check.

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved it. Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem, glad to help!

Comment: Can you mark it as a correct answer